# Hover element over other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a side navigation.  When an icon is clicked it toggles the width of the parent div slim to full content.  Each nav item with in the parent is a div with some supporting text and links. When my icon is clicked the class slimNav is applied so when I hover hover the particular module I want that div to expand a bit add a background and be over top of the surrounding elements.  But what happens is the elements below the item hovered move up.

Here is the html

```
<div class="slimNav" data-bind="foreach: modules">
    <div class="modules" data-bind="click: showModuleNodes">
        <div class="block">
            <i data-bind="css: cssClass" class="fa-alignment"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="headertooltip">
            <span class="headertooltiptext" data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="tooltip">
            <span data-bind="text: name" class="header"></span>
            <ul class="tooltiptext" data-bind="foreach: nodes, visible: nodesVisible">
                <!-- ko template: hasChildren() ? "has-child-node" : "no-child-node" --><!-- /ko -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.slimNav .modules:hover {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index:10;
  background:green;
  width:205px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Here it is in the slim mode
[image]

Now when I hover notice how the elements under the hovered image slide up.

[image]

Comment: It's difficult without being able to see the rest of your CSS, but I would imagine that the "position:absolute" is jumping the menu element out of the standard element flow, causing everything else to move up.

Comment: If you can put together a JSFiddle (or suchlike) demo to recreate the issue, that would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are absolutely positioning your icon on hover, taking the element out of the document layout flow. This frees up the space that the icon was taking up which causes all of the icons below to shift into that newly occupied space.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

To fix this you just need to make sure that your icon is not taken out of the document flow.

One way to do this is to duplicate the icon for the hover state like this:

```css
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__item__hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  background: green;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.nav__item:hover .nav__item__hover {
  display: flex;
}

.nav__item__hover svg {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.nav__item__hover svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav__item">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 5v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
    <div class="nav__item__hover">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 5v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
      Fund Management
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav__item">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 5v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
    <div class="nav__item__hover">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 5v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
      Fund Management
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav__item">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 5v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
    <div class="nav__item__hover">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 5v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2zm12 4c0 1.66-1.34 3-3 3s-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3zm-9 8c0-2 4-3.1 6-3.1s6 1.1 6 3.1v1H6v-1z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
      Fund Management
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `position: absolute` set your position to `position: relative`. Absolute will no longer consider other elements around it.

Comment: yea - i changed that to relative and then removed the positioning from the hover state and changed it to relative and that seems to have solved a portion of the issue

Comment: @TroyBryant That is good to hear it fixed a majority of it. Just remember you may not have to set it to position relative on hover if you already specify it. If you want a popout effect on hover you could use something like this: transform: scale(1.025, 1.025); That will give it a pretty cool effect.